# how to create my own UI in grails?

Tags: grails

i want to learn how to make my own User Interface..
like this..image

[image]

but default of grails like this

[image]

i just want to learn how to make with my own..but i don't know  what should i do..
i tried to install other plugin but not success.
what should i learn to create my own User Interface..?start from where?

Comment: web UI is implemented using HTML and CSS, start with learning them. read some basic html tutorials, etc

Comment: i already can HMTL and  CSS language..

Comment: ok, take a look at twitter-bootstrap or zurb foundation

Comment: "twitter-bootstrap or zurb foundation" it means?

Comment: oh you means framework for CSS?

Comment: yes, I mean css frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create your own user interface using html / css. You will use GSP pages and create whatever type of UI you want. Look at [GSP documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp). Other option is, if you want to change the scaffolded views, you can do so by modifying the scaffolding templates, look at [install-templates](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) command

I would suggest to read the grails reference docs.

Comment: i see the file of the gsp..they are have <meta name="layout" content="secure.gsp"/> where can i find secure.gsp?

Comment: It is a layout, and you can find it in grails-app/view/layout directory. If the layout is provided by a plugin, it will be under same path but inside plugin